# ElasticSearch Migrate Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, elasticsearch-5

I want to migrate data from Amazon AWS ElasticSearch version 2.3 to 5.1 and have created a data snaphsot in S3, now how do I copy those dump files from S3 to ES 5.1?

Comment: is it dump or a snapshot?

Answer (score 0):

You're lucky, according to Elasticsearch documentation:

```
A snapshot of an index created in 2.x can be restored to 5.x.
```

Also, Elasticsearch has:

> repository-s3 for S3 repository support

,which should be very useful in your case, I assuem.

The full guide how to do that is [there](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html). I will try to some of them:

> Before any snapshot or restore operation can be performed, a snapshot
>   repository should be registered in Elasticsearch. The repository
>   settings are repository-type specific. See below for details.

```
PUT /_snapshot/my_backup
{
  "type": "fs",
  "settings": {
        ... repository specific settings ...
  }
}
```

After several others steps, like verifying snapshot, you could restore it:

> A snapshot can be restored using the following command:

```
POST /_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1/_restore
```

Comment: Is there a difference between Restoring Data & Migration?

Comment: in which terms?

Comment: I want to copy my data from ES 2.3 to ES 5.1 now is this process migration or restoring or do they mean the same thing?

Comment: if you made a snapshot, it's a question of restoring data